# Row echelon form and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra

I computed row echelon forms(without fractions) of $3\times3$ matrices and i noticed that the value of the last number on the diagonal $(position $(3,3)$ )$ is equal to the determinant.Is this true, why?

Edit: i used Maple for the calculations
        This seems to work for all matrices

Edit: @algebraicpavel i computed the REF and smith form of the matrix that you posted [image]  this is very weird

Comment: There are plenty of matrices for which this is not true.

Comment: Which row echelon form did you compute?

Comment: matrices i worked with involved a variable, could that be the reason?

Comment: @Saucy O'Path row echelon form via fraction free elimination

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  can you give an example, i cannot find one

Comment: Did you something like the in the computation of  the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form)?

Comment: @LutzL it is similar to to smith form, above the diagonal there arent 0 is the difference

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "without fractions"? Doing row reductions with only integer multiples, or not scaling rows or ... ?

Comment: What would your REF look like for $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$ which is already in REF but its determinant is quite far from $3$?

Comment: Oh I see what is the question now. If you have a look at the standard GE (SGE) and fraction-free GE (FFGE), the only difference is that the working matrix of the FFGE gets multiplied by the current pivot. You can figure out that, provided that the same sequence of pivots is used, the remaining pivot is product of the pivots of SGE and hence the determinant of the matrix. This is true not only for $3\times 3$ matrices though. Now the question is, why is this supposed to be weird?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel everything is weird until you understand it :)